# Composite C1 Custom Routing - Creating custom routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, c1-cms

I am trying to figure out how to create custom routes in composite C1. I have been searching around for hours and came up with noting. I realise you can use pathinfo to slightly customise the route but this really just doesnt do what I need. I basically want to add a few custom routes to override composite C1 if there are any matches

For example I need to map

www.domain.com/job-detail/Executive_Management/HR_Executive/136307 or
www.domain.com/job-detail/Executive_Management/HR_Executive?job=136307

to

www.domain.com/job-seekers/job-search/job-detail?job=136307

Please help. I really like Composite C1 but when it comes to custom routes I find it hard to find any help online.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this one out by having a further dig through the code. I noticed I could add custom routes to the App_Code\Composite\AspNet\MvcPlayer\Route.cs class.

I added this line of code to the RegisterRoutes method....

routes.MapRoute("Job-Listing", "job-detail/{category}/{title}/{id}", new { controller = "JobSearchModule", action = "JobDetail" });

I added this directly above the default route which is important

routes.MapRoute("Default","{controller}/{action}/{id}",new { action = "Index", id = "" });